# Producing persistent message using stompest for python

Tags: python, activemq-classic, stomp

I am not able to send persistent message to AMQ queue using stompest and python.. Dont know what header to use???
Below is source code

```
from stompest.config import StompConfig
from stompest.sync import Stomp
import os

CONFIG = StompConfig('tcp://localhost:61613')
QUEUE = '/queue/myQueue'


if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        client = Stomp(CONFIG)
        client.connect({'login':'#####','passcode':'#####'})
        for i in range(10):
            msg="Test Message" +str(i)
            client.send(QUEUE,msg)
        client.disconnect()
    except Exception,e:
        print e
```

Comment: I got it ....client.connect(QUEUE,msg,headers={'persistant':'true'})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go persistent, you may also want to send you message in a transaction.

```
with client.transaction(receipt='important') as transaction:
        client.send(QUEUE, 'test',{'persistent':'true', StompSpec.TRANSACTION_HEADER: transaction})
```

This way, you can ensure all or none of a set of messages ends up on a queue. If there is an error raised within the transaction block, the message(s) won't be committed to the queue. The same goes for reading messages.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the send line to this :

```
client.send(QUEUE,msg, headers={'persistent' :'true'})
```